# state pattern issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, circular-dependency

I'm creating a simple app which uses different design patterns.
Basically the app is a platform that manages online stores.
For instance I have a store, which has a collection of sales. Each sale will be transitioning from **received state** to **accepted state** to **delivered state**. Also I can transition from **accepted state** to **received state** (*going backwards*). In that last interaction the following problem is showing up -->`TypeError: AcceptedState is not a constructor`
Here's my code

**Estado.js**   --- (status)

```
class Estado {
 
  recibirVenta () {
    return new Error('subclass responsibility')
  }

  aceptarVenta () {
    return new Error('subclass responsibility')
  }

  cancelarVenta () {
    return new Error('subclass responsibility')
  }

  entregarVenta () {
    return new Error('subclass responsibility')
  }
}

module.exports = Estado
```

**EstadoRecibido.js** --- (receivedState)

```
const Estado = require('./estado')
const EstadoAceptado = require('./estadoAceptado')

class EstadoRecibido extends Estado {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.nombre = 'Recibido'
  }

  aceptarVenta (aVenta) {
    aVenta.setEstadoEnvio(new EstadoAceptado())
  }
}

module.exports = EstadoRecibido
```

**EstadoAceptado.js**  --- (acceptedState)

```
const Estado = require('./estado')
const EstadoEntregado = require('./estadoEntregado')
const EstadoRecibido = require('./estadoRecibido')

class EstadoAceptado extends Estado {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.nombre = 'Aceptada'
  }
  
  entregarVenta (aVenta) {
    aVenta.setEstadoEnvio(new EstadoEntregado())
  }

  recibirVenta (aVenta) {
    aVenta.setEstadoEnvio(new EstadoRecibido())
  }
}

module.exports = EstadoAceptado
```

**Venta.js** --- (Sale)

```
class Venta {
  constructor (cliente, items, tipoEnvio) {
    // omitted all other props...
    this.estadoEnvio = new EstadoRecibido()
  }

  aceptarVenta () {
    this.estadoEnvio.aceptarVenta(this)
  }

  recibirVenta () {
    this.estadoEnvio.recibirVenta(this)
  }

  entregarVenta () {
    this.estadoEnvio.entregarVenta(this)
  }

  setEstadoEnvio (aEstado) {
    this.estadoEnvio = aEstado
  } 

  getEstadoEnvio () {
    return this.estadoEnvio
  }
}
module.exports = Venta
```

**Venta.js** is my **context** class. I have a reference to the **current state**.

So far if I do the following

```
const venta = new Venta()
// venta has **ReceivedState** when instanciating.
venta.aceptarVenta()
// venta has **AcceptedState** now
venta.recibirVenta()
// venta fails and says TypeError: EstadoRecibido is not a constructor
```

I think it has something to do with a circular dependency or something like that. For instance if I try to set the state to Deliver state from accepted state there's no issue. The thing is happening when I set one state and try to go to the previous one, in this case accepted to received.

Any ideas? thanks!! *let me know if someone needs the code to be translated to english*

Comment: are you importing the EstadoRecibido class in Venta.js?

Comment: yes, I'm importing it. But that's not the issue. It's instantiating Venta properly with ReceivedState.

Comment: Where is your implementation of `Venta.prototype.setEstadoEnvio` ?

Comment: I guess that should look like  this `setEstadoEnvio(newState) { this.estadoEnvio = newState; }`

Comment: "*I think it has something to do with a circular dependency*" - yes, exactly that. Apply the usual mitigations, such as moving the `require()` statements inside the methods where the constructors are called, or at least after the `module.exports =` assignment. Or switch to ES6 modules, which deal better with this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm the problem was due to a circular dependency.
As user **Bergi** said we have two solutions,
I used the simplest one (*it's just an app for academic purposes*)
Setting **require** inside the methods where constructors are called.

For instance

**EstadoAceptado.js**

```
const Estado = require('./estado')

class EstadoAceptado extends Estado {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.nombre = 'Aceptada'
  }
  
  entregarVenta (aVenta) {
    const EstadoEntregado = require('./estadoEntregado')
    aVenta.setEstadoEnvio(new EstadoEntregado())
  }

  recibirVenta (aVenta) {
    const EstadoRecibido = require('./estadoRecibido')
    aVenta.setEstadoEnvio(new EstadoRecibido())
  }
}

module.exports = EstadoAceptado
```

The other solution is use **ECMA6 modules**, this implies replacing **require** and **module.exports** with **import** and **export**
I think this last one is the best solution, but it is required to configure **jest** properly otherwise it won't recognize **import** statements.
I make the code work with **ECMA6 modules** by setting `type: module` but **jest** requires a bit more setup.
Hope someone finds this useful